# Do storyboards scale well with unit testing?

Tags: ios, cocoa, testing, tdd, storyboard

I am giving a serious look to a new iOS project with Storyboards, and although it seems attractive, I am  concerned about how it will impact my unit tests.

Normally I load my nibs and perform some mixture of integration/functional/unit tests. However with storyboards everything is in one file and I am concerned about the cost of loading and unloading the whole thing during the setUp and tearDown of every single test.

For those of you with TDD experience and Storyboards on large projects. Have you noticed any downside, testing related, when using storyboards?

I am concerned about the performance and keeping my unit tests fast. Maybe there are other issues I have not noticed yet. I would prefer to hear first hand stories from out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in Interface Builder storyboards are presented as one big document, during runtime they are not loaded as a whole. `ibtool` compiles a storyboard to a storyboardc file package, containing nib files for each view controller plus a plist file that contains a mapping between view controller identifiers and nib file names.

So instantiating a view controller from a storyboard is not so much different with storyboards than with individual xib files. In both cases the runtime just instantiates the nib.

Comment: There is also an API to load individual view controllers from a storyboard.